# Underscore do some calculation and return new object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, time-series, click-tracking

I have a time series like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "click",
            "date": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        },
        "total": 5
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        },
        "total": 13
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-02-03T00:00:00+01:00"
        },
        "total": 25
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "click",
            "date": "2015-02-03T00:00:00+01:00"
        },
        "total": 7
    }
]
```

I need to do some calculation and return a similar object, in particular, I need to find the percentage between clicks and hits (clicks/hits*100 of the same date) returning an object like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "ctr",
            "date": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        },
        "total": 38.46
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "ctr",
            "date": "2015-02-03T00:00:00+01:00"
        },
        "total": 28
    }
]
```

Any hint?

Comment: Iterate, do math, and return the values?

Comment: What does "action": "crt" mean in result ?

Comment: how about `var newArray = oldArray.map(function (value) { return /* do transform */; });`?

Comment: Sorry it was "ctr" (click-through-rate)

Comment: Yes I'm trying with some map/groupby/reduce but I don't get the right result yet

Comment: As I see you also want group by date.. is it true ?

Comment: Yes Alexander you are right, the total from click and hit in the same date must be the values for the calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_.groupBy(array, function(el){ return el._id.date; });
```

The above would be how you can group, then you can map over that and calculate what you need. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/j9Htk/114/

Comment: This does only the group by date, I need to do also the calculation between "click" and "hit" and return a new object "ctr"

Comment: For completeness here is the updated fiddle to obtain exactly what requested in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/j9Htk/121/ Thanks snowman4415